# want to create an single /dev/input/eventX for my button interrupts got through several gpios ...?

Tags: driver, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, device-driver

want to create an single /dev/input/eventX  for my button interrupts got through several  gpios  and application handlers will use evtest like utility to detect the registered value or functionality for that gpio which produced interrupt ( similar to keyboard driver)

what i have to do for that ???

i have tried to register the key in platform data of imx6 as shown below after that ????

```
static struct gpio_keys_button imx6q_buttons[] = {


{
                .gpio           = GPIO_SWITCH_INT,
                .code           = KEY_1,
                .desc           = "switch_interrupt",
                .active_low     = 1,
},



};

static struct gpio_keys_platform_data imx6q_button_data = {
        .buttons        = imx6q_buttons,
        .nbuttons       = ARRAY_SIZE(imx6q_buttons),
};

static struct platform_device imx6q_button_device = {
        .name           = "gpio-keys",
        .id             = -1,
        .num_resources  = 0,
        .dev            = {
                .platform_data = &imx6q_button_data,
        }
};

static void __init imx6q_add_device_buttons(void)
{
        platform_device_register(&imx6q_button_device);
}
```